# What are the advantages and disadvantages of Liftweb Comet?

Tags: scala, comet, lift

What are the advantages and disadvantages of Liftweb Comet over other HTTP Server push technologies?
- How scalable is liftweb comet?
- design issues and dependencies
etc..,

Answer (score 2):

Comet is a generic term for Ajax HTTP server push. See this link for more details:

http://exploring.liftweb.net/master/index-11.html

I believe this is the only way to implement server push with Lift.

The advantage of using Comet over Ajax polling are well described in the link above (reduced traffic/better responsiveness).

According to this source Lift Comet is most scalable on Jetty due to the use of non-blocking IO, but it seems to be a controversial topic:

[Comet VS Ajax polling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975290/comet-vs-ajax-polling)

[Java I/O vs. Java new I/O (NIO) with Linux NPTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057853/java-i-o-vs-java-new-i-o-nio-with-linux-nptl/4253926#4253926)

If you gave more details on the alternatives to Comet you consider it would be easier to give you the relative advantages and disadvantages.