# Why Java NIO can be superior to standard Java sockets?

Tags: java, sockets, nio

Recently I was playing with Java sockets and NIO for writing a server. Although it is still not really clear for me why Java NIO could be superior to standard sockets. When writing a server using either of these technologies, in most cases it comes down to having a dispatcher thread that accepts connections and further passes them to working threads.

I have read that in a threaded-model we need a dedicated thread per connection but still we can create a thread pool of a fixed size and reuse them to handle different connections (so that a cost of creation and tear down of threads is reduced).

But with Java NIO it looks similar. We have one thread that accepts requests and some worker thread(s) processing data when it is received.

An example I found where Java NIO would be better is a server that maintains many non-busy connections, like a chat client or http server. But can't really understand why.

Comment: See related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267306/java-net-versus-java-nio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several distinct reasons.

1. Using multiplexed I/O with a `Selector` can save you a lot of threads, which saves you a lot of thread stacks, which save you a lot of memory. On the other hand it moves scheduling from the operating system into your program, so it can cost you a bit of CPU, and it will also cost you a *lot* of programming complication. Given that select() was designed when the alternative was more processes, not more threads, it is in fact debatable whether the extra complication is really worth it, as against using threads and spending the programming money saved on more memory.
2. `MappedByteBuffers` are a slightly faster way of reading files than either java.io or using `java.nio.channels` with `ByteBuffers`.
3. If you are just copying from one channel to another, using 'direct' buffers saves you from having to copy data from the native JNI space into the JVM space and back again; or using the FileChannel.transferTo() method can save you from copying data from kernel space into user space.

Comment: I have found another reason. Please let me know if it is correct. When we use thread per event model we can better utilize the threads. In the thread per connection model the thread can be taken out from the thread pool but remain idle, e.g. when there is no data exchange on the connection. With NIO we don't have such situation because once the event is processed the thread is returned to the pool. The connection still remains open but if there is no activity on it, no threads from the pool are used for it.

Comment: @Janek Thats not 'another' reason: it's just a special case of point 1: 'it saves you a lot of threads'.

Answer (score 1):

Even though NIO supports the Dispatcher model, NIO Sockets are *blocking* by default and when you use them as such they can be faster than either plain IO or non-blocking NIO for a small (< 100) connections.  I also find blocking NIO simpler to work with than non-blocking NIO.

I use non-blocking NIO when I want to use busy waiting.  This allows be to have a thread which never gives up the CPU but this is only useful in rare cases i.e. where latency is ciritical.

Comment: When you say blocking NIO do you mean the blocking select() method?

Comment: @Janek no, I mean don't use Selectors at all.  They are not needed for blocking NIO and you may wish to avoid them for non-blocking NIO as well. ;)  For blocking NIO you have one reader thread per connection which can scale up to 1000 connections. Just like plain IO.  If you need 10K+ connections on one process, then selectors makes sense.

Comment: You *can't* use Selectors with blocking I/O in Java.

Answer (score 0):

From my benchmarks the real strength (besides threading model) is, that it consumes less memory bandwith (Kernel<=>Java). E.g. if you open several UDP NIO Multicast Channels and have high traffic you will notice that at a certain number of processes with each new process throughput of all running UDP receivers gets lower. With the traditional socket API i start 3 receiving processes with full throughput. If i start the 4th I reach a limit and received data/second will lower on all the running processes. With nio i can start about 6 processes until this effect kicks in.

I think this is mostly because NIO kind of directly bridges to native or kernel memory, while the old socket copies buffers to the VM process space.

Important in GRID computing and high load server apps (10GBit network or infiniband).